# Collapsible panel in Devexpress without browser issues

Tags: devexpress

Is there a collapsible panel with DevExpress without having browser issues?.

TU

Answer (score 0):

You can customise ASPxRoundPanel or use ASPxNavbar. I use ASPxNavBar although I read that it can be overhead for this task.
[Collapsible ASPxRoundPanel sample.](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E143.aspx)
[ASPxNavBar demos.](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/NavBar/DataBinding.aspx)